# Is it possible to export foxpro data to excel using php

Tags: php, mysql, foxpro, dbf

I'm wondering is it possible to export foxpro data (.dbf) to excel using php only without converting data to MySql ?

Comment: you need to manually convert it first to excel http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms710907(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you can open the FoxPro data-source via OLE  DB or ODBC, you can treat it as any other recordsource and write it to excel, HTML, JSON, etc.

Of course, if you have a windows machine and a copy of FoxPro, you can just export the DBF's to an Excel 5.0 XLS file, or a CSV, HTML table, or (for some latter versions) XML.

Answer (score 0):

It IS possible, however the PHP accessors will NOT work with MEMO data.

You can use the dbase php functions to do so.